# TFS 2017 20 users application licensing question

Tags: tfs

I need to setup TFS 2017 for 20 developers/analysts. Usage will be mostly for code repository, therefore 1 server only with TFS 2017/8 and SQL 2017. I need to know the licensing requirements for TFS application only, I know for SQL. We plan on using SSRS, but not SharePoint. Will a Visual Studio subscription cover for the TFS license for server and does it have to be Enterprise or Professional subscription is OK? What license will be the most economical for the rest of 19 users?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

> Will a Visual Studio subscription cover for the TFS license for server
>   and does it have to be Enterprise or Professional subscription is OK?

Yes, Visual Studio subscriptions include a server license for TFS, plus a TFS CAL for the subscriber

> What license will be the most economical for the rest of 19 users?

It's based on your real requirements. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access, which is free.

If the users want to work on codes, then they need client access licenses...

Extensions to TFS such as Test Manager, Package Management, and Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions are included with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions and many others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no Visual Studio subscription is required.

Please see [Team Foundation Server 2018 Licensing](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/) for details, it also applies to TFS 2017.